# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to make a code that print out calendar with some given months and years.
My code look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""import calender"""

import calendar
import datetime

""" begin function """


def get_the_first_day_of_the_week(month, year):
    day_of_week = datetime.date(year, month, 1).weekday()
    return


def print_out_calender(months, years):
    this_month = int(months)
    this_year = int(years)
    new = get_the_first_day_of_the_week(this_month, this_year)
    new = int(new)
    calendar.setfirstweekday(new)
    calendar.monthcalendar(this_month, this_year)
    return


print_out_calender(12, 2017)
```

i expect it to print out matrix of date but i got an error like this:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "./practice12.py", line 25, in <module>
    print_out_calender(12, 2017)
  File "./practice12.py", line 19, in print_out_calender
    new = int(new)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

i am new to python and coding so can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Did you mean `return day_of_week` inside of `get_the_first_day_of_the_week`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new = get_the_first_day_of_the_week(this_month, this_year)
```

assigns the return value of `get_the_first_day_of_the_week()` to `new`.

However, `get_the_first_day_of_the_week()` returns nothing, i.e. `None`.

Change the function to return something (presumably `day_of_the_week`) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `new` is `None` in the code. `int` cannot take None type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Return **day_of_week** from get_the_first_day_of_the_week

Answer (score 0):

You are returning None in `get_the_first_day_of_the_week` function. Either return `day_of_week` or make `day_of_week` a global variable.